# Like some opinion on designing for SaaS platform

Tags: user-expectation, branding

I'm in charge of UX/UI of a range of applications for a big HR player and they like to market their applications as a set of modules in a SaaS platform model. I'm keeping UX consistent over all applications through the implementation of a design system but I'm thinking of giving each application its own logo, name and color (so they stand out and users know which application they're using as some of them seem similar). I'm not sure this is a good way to go though, especially the different color. There would be max 10 applications so I'd have enough colors to choose from. I can't find any real world examples where the same was done either. Do you have any opinion or do you know any examples? Thx

Comment: You can't find any real world examples of applications system with different names, color, logos belonging to a main company????? : Microsoft, Adobe, Apple, Google...

Comment: My bad, I just didn't frame the context right. All these applications have the same consistent content like buttons and background colors, they just differ in a different app icon color or minor changes in layout like a different header background color. What I'm aiming for is a set of applications where each application has different colored backgrounds and button colors. I haven't seen any of those yet.

Comment: I see. If this is the case you have an example right in front of you: visit all the Stackexchange sites, they all have the same layout, buttons and actions, changing just the header, background and button colors.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have to look that far! It doesn't completely match what I'm after but it's a very nice example indeed. Thx

Comment: You will find plenty of examples when you search for white label SaaS products. [Maybe this article is helpful.](https://www.profitwell.com/recur/all/saas-white-label)

Comment: nice, thank you jazZRo!

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind to try and keep the branding and visual design manageable is to consider a higher level of grouping for the different applications. That way, instead of creating separate branding, you can simply come up with a smaller number of brands, each with their own sub brand. This reduces the risk when you have to merge different products or split them up, because it keeps the number of brands (and the rules applied to them) to a minimum.

A good test is to look at the licensing of the various products, and see how many of the products are used by customers. This gives you an idea of how many different brands are exposed to a typical customer, and how confusing it might be for them. If you look at the problem from the customer's perspective, it might be less of a problem than you think it is (even though it is still a big problem to manage from your perspective).

You can see [all the StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#) in one page and get an idea of how they are branded (or not).